# MySql Unique ids / Data Extraction from Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a question regarding unique ids and data extraction from a mysql database. When joining tables with LEFT JOIN mysql commands and other mysql commands how is it possible to append a unique ID onto the item your extracting from the MySql database? Is their anyway to give the item a unique ID? Thanks Everyone!

```
SELECT y.`name` AS `year` , ma.`name` AS make, mo.`name` AS model 
FROM bhph_car_models mo 
LEFT JOIN bhph_car_years `y` ON y.`id` = mo.`car_year_id` AND y.`active` =1 
LEFT JOIN bhph_car_makes ma ON ma.`id` = mo.`car_make_id` AND ma.`active` =1 
WHERE mo.`active` =1 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Thanks Everyone!